# enum and NSDictionary to define list of valid elements in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, design-patterns

I try to understand how to define a list of valid elements for a class: 
Let's say i have a class `People` and i need to accept only 3 strings as possible valid names 
`@"Luke"`,`@"Paul"`,`@"Mark"`.

I thought to use a combination of enum and NSDictionary this way (but i'm obviously not sure about the correctness of this method):

```
//INTERFACE*********************
typedef enum {  
 Luke,Paul,Mark
}ValidName;

@interface Person : NSObject{  
  // some code

}

@end


//IMPLEMENTATION*******************
@interface Person(private){
 NSMutableDictionary *_validNamesDict;
}
@end

@interface Person:NSObject
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _validNamesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_validNamesDict setObject: @"Luke" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: Luke]];
        [_validNamesDict setObject: @"Paul" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: Paul]];
        [_validNamesDict setObject: @"Mark" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: Mark]];
    }

    return self;
}

//Some code ....
```

Now in the rest of the class i refer to this name with:

```
[_validNameDict objecWithKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: Luke]];
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best method. Could you suggest me a valid way to manage this situation ? I read something about the use of extern keyword and definition to static variable into class... is it maybe a better method?

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way to do what you want, but it's unclear what you actually want to do. What are these the only valid values *for*? In what cases are these values used and in what cases does their validity matter?

Comment: @Chuck i'm working on a library for an API where some functions takes only specific values. So i need a way to limit developer which use the library to these values only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want here is a *set*, not a *map*--that is, an `NSSet`, not an `NSDictionary`.

Let's say you have the set `validNames` and you want to determine if the name `n` is in the set. Once your set is initialized, just do the following:

```
BOOL nameIsValid = [validNames containsObject:n];
```

Comment: @"Jonathan Grynspan" in your opinion which is it better way to define the NSSet: in init function or by a static variable ?

Comment: You'll have to initialize it at some point but if it will have the same content every time, use a single `static` instance and initialize it in the class' `+initialize` method (see the documentation on that method for how to use it.)